# Want to return a key pressed in python 3.1

Tags: python, keypress

I want a script that will return the keypress as soon as the user press even it has time limit. I used time limit to get the user input to return but my code is not working. I tried the following.

```
def answer(timeout):
    print "Enter the answer"
    stop = time.time() + timeout
    r=['a','b','c','d']
    while True:
        if msvcrt.getche() in r:
            return msvcrt.getche()

        else:
            if time.time() > stop:
                return 'O'
```

But i'm getting only 'ÿ' till timeout, even if i press any key, it is not detected.
Here i need a code that will return a|b|c|d when it is pressed or O when time exceeds.

Comment: Is it just for windows platform?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html Did you read this? It says Windows on top. And the name of the module **ms**vcrt says it's Microsoft-specific.

Comment: @Myjab:  Could you clarify, do you mean both windows and linux?

Comment: You might want the curses library for linux.

Comment: By using curses and other examples given, i can do any one operation only. (ie) i can detect a keypress or i can assume none to my return value after a particular time. Actually i need to get the key pressed within time limit and if no key is pressed then return default. Please help me